# How to move an item from one list to a second list by dragging and dropping it on a div instead of a list

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to move an item from one list to a second list by dragging and dropping it on a div instead of a list in Angular Material, like on the picture.

Thanks for help!

[image]

Comment: Use `@angular/cdk` [example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/additional-samples/drag-drop) [demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/additional-samples/drag-drop)

Answer (score 1):

I think your should check examples of angular material, they have solution to for drag and drop also for your scenario you can check [here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists)

Comment: I've checked all the examples with Angular material, but there's nothing like that